# submitting accepts_nested_attributes and failed validations in parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Thanks in advance for your help.

This may get a little long.

**Setup**
*Models:*

```
class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many    :collection_ownerships
    has_many    :items
    has_many    :users, :through => :collection_ownerships


    validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 25 }
    validates :description, length: { maximum: 100 }
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :collection
    has_many :item_ownerships, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :item_ownerships

    validates :name, :presence => true, length: { maximum: 50 }
    validates :collection, :presence => true

end

class ItemOwnership < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to  :item
    belongs_to  :user

    validates :user, :presence => true
    validates :item, :presence => true
end
```

*Controllers*

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController

    before_action :authenticate_user!
    before_filter(:except => :toggle_item_owned_state) do
        @collection = current_user.collections.find(params[:collection_id])
        @item_list = @collection.items
    end

    def toggle_item_owned_state

        @item = Item.find_by_id(params[:item_id])
        @io = @item.item_ownerships.find_by_user_id(current_user)

        @result = @io.update_attributes(:owned => @io.owned? ? false : true)

        respond_to do |format|
            if @result
                format.html { }
                format.js {} 
            else
                format.html { }
                format.js {} 
            end
        end
    end

    def index
    end

    def new
        @item = @collection.items.new
        @item_ownership = @item.item_ownerships.build(:owned => true, :user => current_user, :item => @item)
    end

    def create

        @item ||= @collection.items.new(item_params)
        @item_ownership ||= @item.item_ownerships.build(:user => current_user, :item => item)

        if @item.save
            redirect_to collection_items_path(@collection)
        else
            flash.now[:alert] = "There was a problem saving this item."
            render "new"
        end
    end

    def edit
        @item = @collection.items.find_by_id(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        @item = @collection.items.find_by_id(params[:id])


        if @item.update_attributes(item_params)
            redirect_to collection_items_path(@collection)
        else
            flash.now[:alert] = "There was a problem saving this item."
            render "edit"
        end
    end

    def item_params
        params.require(:item).permit(:name,
            item_ownerships_attributes: [:id, :owned ])
    end
end
```

*View*

```
<div class="row">
    <span class="col-sm-12">
        <div id="add_item">
            <%= form_for [@collection, @item] do |f| %>
            <div class="form-group <%= 'has-error has-feedback' if @item.errors[:name].present? %>">
                <label class="sr-only" for="item_name">Item Name</label>
                <%= f.text_field :name, :autofocus => true, :placeholder => "Item Name", :class => "form-control", :'aria-describedBy' => "itemNameBlock" %>
                <% if @item.errors[:name].present? %>
                        <span id="itemNameBlock" class="error">Item <%= @item.errors[:name].first %></span>
                <% end %>
                <%= f.fields_for :item_ownerships do |io| %>
                    <%= io.check_box :owned %> Owned
                <% end %>
            </div>
            <div id="signin_button_row">
                <%= f.submit "Save", :class => "form-control green_button" %>
                <span id="forgot_my_password" class="right-justify">
                    <%= link_to "cancel", collection_items_path(@collection), :class => "new_colors terms" %>
                </span>
            </div>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    </span>
</div>
```

**Symptom of problem:**
When I submit the form in a failure situation (ie name is not provided), the form currently detects the validation and displays the error, however, I now get two checkboxes called 'owned' appearing in the form.  Each failing submission adds an additional checkbox (as per attached image).[image]

Can anyone help?

**Update**
This issue has taken a turn for the strange.  I haven't changed anything (I know, I know, you don't believe it) other than restarting the server but now nothing is saved even with valid data.   I am getting validation errors saying:

**Validation failed: Item ownerships user can't be blank, Item ownerships item can't be blank**

Comment: Exact same issue as the question you just asked and the exact same solution: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_associated

Comment: I'm not sure this is the problem.   I added validates_associated to item_ownerships on both 'item' and 'user' and the problem still continues to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller `create` action you have

```
def create
    @item ||= @collection.items.new(item_params)
    @item_ownership ||= @item.item_ownerships.build(:user => current_user)

    if @item.save
        redirect_to collection_items_path(@collection)
    else
        flash.now[:alert] = "There was a problem saving this item."
        render "new"
    end
end
```

Problem is on third line when you assign `@item_ownership` this variable is always empty at this time so code after `=` is executed. `@item.item_ownerships.build(:user => current_user)` always build new `item_ownership` and stores it into `@item` instance. So after first call of create you will have two `item_ownerships` first is from form and second is newly created. If validation fails and you send form again you will have three instances of `item_ownerships` two from the form a one newly created etc.

Answer (score 0):

@edariedl was on the right track in addressing the initial response.   The second line is completely unnecessary.

The second issue mentioned in the update I addressed in a separate question found here: [Losing mind over validation failure saving nested models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30520786/losing-mind-over-validation-failure-saving-nested-models)