# Losing mind over validation failure saving nested models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Losing my mind.  Have been reading docs and example and haven't been able to figure this out.   I'm probably missing something really obvious.

Models

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :collection
    has_many :item_ownerships, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :item_ownerships

    validates :collection, :presence => true
end

class ItemOwnership < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to  :item
    belongs_to  :user

    validates :user_id, :presence => true
    validates :item_id, :presence => true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :item_ownerships
end
```

Controller

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController

    before_action :authenticate_user!
    before_filter(:except => :toggle_item_owned_state) do
        @collection = current_user.collections.find(params[:collection_id])
    end

    def new
        @item = Item.new collection_id: @collection.id
        @item_ownership = @item.item_ownerships.build(:owned => true, :user => current_user, :item => @item)
    end

    def create
        @item = @collection.items.build(item_params)
        @item_ownership = @item.item_ownerships.build(:user => current_user, :item => @item)
        #byebug

        if @item.save!
            redirect_to collection_items_path(@collection)
        else
            flash.now[:alert] = "There was a problem saving this item."
            render "new"
        end
    end

    def item_params
        params.require(:item).permit(:name,
            item_ownerships_attributes: [:id, :owned, :user, :item])
    end
end
```

View

```
<%= form_for [@collection, @item] do |f| %>
                <div class="form-group <%= 'has-error has-feedback' if @item.errors[:name].present? %>">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="item_name">Item Name</label>
                    <%= f.text_field :name, :autofocus => true, :placeholder => "Item Name", :class => "form-control", :'aria-describedBy' => "itemNameBlock" %>
                    <% if @item.errors[:name].present? %>
                            <span id="itemNameBlock" class="error">Item <%= @item.errors[:name].first %></span>
                    <% end %>
                    <%= f.fields_for :item_ownerships do |io| %>
                        <%= io.check_box :owned %> Owned
                    <% end %>
                </div>
                <div id="signin_button_row">
                    <%= f.submit "Save" %>
                    <span id="forgot_my_password" class="right-justify">
                        <%= link_to "cancel", collection_items_path(@collection) %>
                    </span>
                </div>
            <% end %>
```

When I submit the form, it fails with the following error:

**Validation failed: Item ownerships user can't be blank, Item ownerships item can't be blank**

Using a debugger, I've looked at the values in @item and @item_ownerships just prior to saving and they are the following:

```
(byebug) @item
#<Item id: nil, name: "test", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, collection_id: 71>
(byebug) @item_ownership
#<ItemOwnership id: nil, user_id: 52, item_id: nil, owned: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

I assume that when the form is submitted, @item is instantiated, all the values in the associations are populated and saved.

I will continue to try to find a similar problem or article, but any help would be appreciated.

**Update**

It is interesting to note that if I remove the fields_for in the view for the checkbox both models are saved with no validation errors.

```
Post Parameters provided as requested:
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"TMPET9Oq9eH8vbk7REVnmKEB5X8BqycSkio5XXdwsLSVqs8/Soz+uMyGJJZCnpOQgbwBESnkKmLts8oQKKiG/Q==",
 "item"=>{"name"=>"testg",
 "item_ownerships_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"owned"=>"1"}}},
 "commit"=>"Save",
 "collection_id"=>"71"}
```

Comment: please post your POST params.

Comment: I've provided the info and also made an observation.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while but I finally figured it out.   I completely misunderstood how nested models work.

In 'create', both models (items and item_ownerships_ are built using item_params in the line:

```
@item = @collection.items.build(item_params)
```

As a result, the following line which instantiates @item_ownerships was unnecessary.  The validation failure occurs in 2 ways:

1) user is failing because there is no user information passed through item_params
2) item is failing because I should have been performing the validation using :inverse_of (refer to this article: http://michaelwelburn.com/2014/02/10/rails-4-nested-object-creation-and-parent-presence-validation-error/)

In any case, thanks to anyone who responded and is considering responding.